# String tags and rearranging order from output

Tags: php, curl, strip

how would I go about stripping away the `" -` and `<b>` tags from the `curl` output below? i tried `strip_tags` but then I do not know how to rearrange the order

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://beta.test123.com/archive.csv?s=BLOGS&f=lc1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**curl output**

```
"4:01pm - <b>n1234</b>",+0.50
```

**Trying to achieve the following format, outputted to a blog.inc file**

```
n1234
+0.50
4:01 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = strip_tags($out);
$result = str_replace(["- ", '"'], '', $result); // remove unnecessary chars
$result = str_replace(',',' ', $result); // change comma to space for explode
$array = explode(' ', $result); // explode by space

//here result - array with needed values
$array[1] // should be n1234
$array[0] // should be 4:01pm
$array[2] // should be +0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?
I use [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the parts of the string, and I use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the bold tag.

To rearrange the items to your order I use [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
$str = '"4:01pm - <b>n1234</b>",+0.50';

preg_match('/\"(.*?)\s-\s(.*?)\",(.*)/', strip_tags($str), $matches);
unset($matches[0]); // unset [0] because that is the full match.
$matches[] = array_shift($matches); // takes first item and makes it last.

echo implode("<br>\n", $matches);
//var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
n1234
+0.50
4:01pm
```

https://3v4l.org/smQIV

EDIT; I see now that you want "4:01 **PM**" and with a space. Not sure if it's a typo or not but the following code should make that happen, just add it before the implode.

```
$matches[2] = date("g:i A", strtotime($matches[2]));
```

Comment: i tried appending your code to my exist $str = $ch; but no luck, am i missing something?

Comment: i had to added CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and also use `curl_exec($ch)` ... everything seems to work except for line separation. its still all on one line

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Use `<br>\n` as implode string.